# Dimension Requirements, Intuit Partner Platform - Intuit Anywhere, App and Toolbar Icons and Screenshot

Tags: quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

In the [Intuit Partner Platform - Intuit Anywhere - Publish your App](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0040_Publishing_Your_App/4._Submit_content_for_Publishing) Section it is mentioned to provide the Following

1)  App Logo - this will appear on the Intuit App Center.
2)  Toolbar App Icon - this will appear alongside the app name in the Intuit "blue dot" menu.
3)  App Screenshot or Banner Image - this will appear on the right side of the banner on the Intuit App Center.

Note:  These must conform to the Intuit branding guidelines under the legal agreement.

What are the dimension requirements for the above images?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 16x16,150x150 the info is on the form when you submit your application for publishing

Comment: 16px x 16px for both?  What about the App Screenshot or Banner Image?

Comment: App Logo (150x150)

Toolbar 16x16 App Icon

For the Banner Image, I believe it is referring to the feature images on the app card, which are 1024W x 768H pixels.
As Jarred mentioned, you will see the dimensions when publishing.